# Check if a certain value has been logged to the console

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make an adventure game and am trying to check if the value `100 ms have elapsed` is in the console.log.

Please comment a fix or some way I can do that i would really be happy if you helped!!

All I need is a way for the code to check if the `console.log()` has a certain value in it. I need a fix or way to check if it has that value.

```js
var ground = createSprite(0, 425);
ground.setAnimation("ground_grass");
ground.width = 1000000000;

ground.setCollider("rectangle", 0, 25, 1000000000, 0.5);
var player = createSprite(200, 0);
player.setAnimation("player_fall");
player.scale = 0.4;

var hpbar = createSprite(85, 25);
hpbar.setAnimation("hpbar");
hpbar.scale = 0.3;

function draw() {
  background(rgb(102, 204, 255));
  //player mechanics
  player.collide(ground);
  player.setCollider("rectangle", -19, 75, 120, 210);
  //move right
  if (keyDown("d")) {
    player.setAnimation("player_run");
    ground.x = ground.x + 6;
  } else if ((keyWentUp("d"))) {
    player.setAnimation("player_idle");
  }
  //move left
  if (keyDown("a")) {
    player.setAnimation("player_run_left");
    ground.x = ground.x - 6;
  } else if ((keyWentUp("a"))) {
    player.setAnimation("player_idle_left");
  }
  //crouch
  if (keyWentDown("s")) {
    player.setAnimation("player_crouch");
  } else if ((keyWentDown("w"))) {
    player.setAnimation("player_idle");
  }
  //jump
  if (keyWentDown("w")) {
    player.setAnimation("player_jump");
    player.velocityY = -7;
  }
  if (player.y < 200) {
    player.velocityY = player.velocityY + 1.5;
    player.setAnimation("player_fall");
  }
  if (player.y > 300) {
    player.setAnimation("player_idle");
    player.velocityY = 0;
    player.y = 300;
  }
  //slide right
  if (keyWentDown("e")) {
    ground.velocityX = ground.velocityX + 25;
    player.setAnimation("player_slide");
  } else if ((keyWentUp("e"))) {
    ground.velocityX = ground.velocityX - 25;
    player.setAnimation("player_idle");
  }
  //slide left
  if (keyWentDown("q")) {
    ground.velocityX = ground.velocityX - 25;
    player.setAnimation("player_slide_left");
  } else if ((keyWentUp("q"))) {
    ground.velocityX = ground.velocityX + 25;
    player.setAnimation("player_idle_left");
  }
  //attack
  if (keyWentDown("space")) {
    player.setAnimation("attack");
    player.x = player.x + 0.001;
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("10000 milliseconds have elapsed");
    }, 10000);
    if (player.x + 0.001) {
      player.setAnimation("attack");
    }
    if (console.log("10000 milliseconds have elapsed")) {
      player.setAnimation("player_idle");
    }
  }
  drawSprites();
}
```

Comment: There's no standard API for testing what's in the console log. `console.log()` just makes a log message, it doesn't return a value that you can test with `if`. If you need to do this, you need to monkey-patch `console.log` so it saves what it wrote someplace you can test.

Comment: But why are you doing it like this? `console.log()` is meant as a debugging tool, not something that should be used for normal user interaction. Anything your application needs to remember should be saved in its own data structures.

Comment: You can't really do that, however it's not how your code should be working. If you want to know that 100ms has elapsed, use a timeout, or hook a promise to whatever async logic you called, or use a MutationObserver etc. The point is, there's a better way to do whatever you need, if you can give a much better description of your use case.

Comment: Well all im trying to do is for it to delay it from changing back to the idle animation after the attack since if i do if keyWentUp then it won't work and will just stay idle or change to fast.

Comment: So put the `player.setAnimation("player_idle");` line ***inside*** the `setTimeout()` where you actually log that line to the console...?

Comment: i just tried that and the console log said "WARNING: Line: 70: setTimeout() callback parameter value (undefined) is not a function."

Comment: I don't see any code that might write `100 ms have elapsed`.  I see code for `console.log("10000 milliseconds have elapsed")`  Just write your code right there.  Maybe set a global flag or fire off a callback or resolve a promise or something.  _"check if the value is in the console.log"_ sounds like an after-the-fact way of thinking about it.

Comment: Still didn't work ;-; I just need to add a like half or full second delay.